# select yesterday date in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the following where condition as 0 to select the value on today's date

```
where (DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.createdon, GETDATE()) = 0 
      or DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.modifiedon, GETDATE()) = 0)
```

But I need to select the yesterday values in where condition .If i use -1 instead of 0 . its not returning the yesterday date values.

```
where (DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.createdon, GETDATE()) = -1 
      or DateDiff(d, FilteredPhoneCall.modifiedon, GETDATE()) = -1)
```

Comment: Are you using sqllite or sql server? They're different databases. Please only use relevant tags (C# has nothing to do with this either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
* 
FROM yourTable
WHERE 
(FilteredPhoneCall.createdon >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND FilteredPhoneCall.createdon < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
OR
(FilteredPhoneCall.modifiedon >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND FilteredPhoneCall.modifiedon < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the between condition;

```
WHERE FilteredPhoneCall.createdon between DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 Where FilteredPhoneCall.createdon >= DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
WHERE CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) =CAST(FilteredPhoneCall.createdon AS DATE)
```